# Disable or remove wordpress post via email

Tags: wordpress, email, post

Any way to disable or remove wordpress post via email?
I tried adding the following code in functions.php, but I still see 'Post via email' under Settings > Writing:

`apply_filters( 'enable_post_by_email_configuration', false );`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code
`add_filter( 'enable_post_by_email_configuration', '__return_false', 100 );`

from [code.tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/50-filters-of-wordpress-filters-11-20--cms-21296)

It does remove the section from the WordPress admin. I'm assuming it disables the 'Post via email' function entirely.

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked for me

```
add_filter( 'enable_post_by_email_configuration', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This was removed from wordpress in version 3.7.

If you still see it in the user profile screen then it is likely added by jetpack.

Answer (score 0):

Our free plugin [Disable Post Via Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-post-via-email-littlebizzy/) disables both the Post Via Email functionality and the associated UI options, using a similar filter as previously shared:

```
add_filter('enable_post_by_email_configuration', '__return_false', PHP_INT_MAX);
```